# How to click checkbox manager can update membership list on Active Directory group using PowerShell

Tags: powershell

I'm trying to find a way with PowerShell to check if the box **Manager can update membership list** on an active directory group.

I have restore script for a SQL Server database and the script create the following related to the AD groups

1. Create AD groups for the unit
2. Create the default db AD security
3. Create logins and link to AD groups

and a popup box will remind you to update the "Manager Can Update Membership List" box in AD manually. Is there any way in PowerShell to check the box after the AG group is created?